# React Native: How do you disable the idle timer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm making a timer app with RN, but after about 1 minute 50 seconds, the device's screen gets dark and prepares to sleep.

Comment: I think what you're really asking is [how to keep the screen on.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keep-screen-on)

Comment: That only supports Android as of right now.  I see that the author does have iOS support on his todo list though.

Comment: [I found this immediately after it.](https://github.com/corbt/react-native-keep-awake) Gotta hone that Google-fu

Comment: Would prefer if I didn't have to use someone else's package, but thanks anyways.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to. It's just that keeping the screen awake varies between devices and it isn't automatically built into React Native at the moment. You could examine that package and find the relevant code (it's not much) and integrate it into your own stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `react-native-idle-timer`

see : [React Native Idle Timer](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-idle-timer)

Comment: I am using this, but do you know how to stop it from popping in parents components, is there a way to stop it?

Comment: you can make use of the js set timeout , which gives u the timer Id .
Add this timerId to the redux state and u can stop this timer based on a condition in other screens.